# AnalysisException: Multi-column In predicates are not supported in the DELETE condition

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I am doing the following in my databricks code. The code is trying to delete some rows from my table under conditions which seam simple to me.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = int(look_back_days))
yesterday_str = yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

query = f"""DELETE FROM table_name a WHERE  AWB_ID  IN (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.DW_CRT_RUN_DT >= '{yesterday_str}' or a.dw_upd_run_dt >= '{yesterday_str}' and a.awb_Stus_cd = 'VOID' and a.dw_upd_pgm_id = 'DSPD0580')"""

spark.sql(query)
```

However, I got the following error.

> AnalysisException: Multi-column In predicates are not supported in the DELETE condition

I also put what was suggested by @kombajn-zbożowy below, but it is still throwing the same error

[image]

Comment: were you able to resolve this? i am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `SELECT *` - it is expecting a list of `AWB_ID`s, but you give it all columns. Use:

```
DELETE FROM table_name a WHERE AWB_ID  IN (SELECT AWB_ID FROM a WHERE ...)
```

Comment: Hi @kombajn-zbożowy  I followed what you said, it is still giving same error

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM abc WHERE field IN (SELECT field FROM def);`

If you continue to get exceptions, run the sub-query on its own. You may get something like:

`Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name 'field' cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following?`

It is possible that you are trying to reference a non-existing field and this exception pops up.